# Не все тесты прошел

Tags: python

Решил задачку на питоне, но не прошел 2 теста из 6, каких неизвестно. Пожалуйста помогите, а то совсем уже не понимаю. Вот условие:

2. За один ход один из двух крайних кузнечиков (то есть с плитки A или с плитки C) может перепрыгнуть через среднего кузнечика (плитка B) и встать на плитку, которая находится ровно посередине между двумя оставшимися кузнечиками (то есть между B и C или A и B соответственно). Если между двумя оставшимися кузнечиками находится чётное число плиток, то он может выбрать любую из двух центральных плиток.

Входные данные
Программа получает на вход три целых числа A, B и C (1ABC1000), записанных в отдельных строках.

Выходные данные
Выведите одно число — наибольшее количество ходов, которое может продолжаться игра.

Вот код:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
l = (c-b) + (b-a) - 2
s = 0
while (l>0):
    s= s+1
    l = l >> 1
print(s)
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как усовершенствовать это решение

Comment: Что-то я в задаче вопроса не вижу

Comment: Прошу прощения. Сейчас добавлю

Comment: Эээ? Фибоначчи? Кажется вы не то скопировали

Comment: Да-да. Уже заметил. Еще раз приношу свои извинения...

Comment: Во входных данный 1<=a<b<c<100. Не помещается...

Comment: контрпример на решение: `1 3 5`... Проблема, как минимум, в том, что положение `B` в твоём решении ни как не учитывается...

Comment: Ясно. А можете помочь конкретно, как изменить свое решение. Просто в условии сказано, что положение b и не должно учитываться